# Wordpress page loading gray boxes randomly while I scroll during page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

On [my site](http://cprosdev.com/dee/product-category/dresses/alldresses/) as the page is loading I noticed, on both mobile and desktop, that as I scroll the screen gets a gray box. It's very jarring. I also noticed it on my [gallery](http://cprosdev.com/dee/gallery-2/) page.

Any idea what's happening or try to fix it? I've never run into this issue on other sites.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that you load EVERYTHING in your your `<head>` tag. [image]

So what happens is that your browser is blocked by getting all of the files first, to be more precise 123 files. Then it tries to read everything and make sense of it. From what I've noticed there must be some jQuery for scrolling as well, which adds even more stress.

Try to put all of the `<script>` tags at the bottom of your body. This allows browser load them after it reads the styling and content. That's probably the quickest fix.

### edit

Also there there are multiple copies of same file loaded and multiple versions of same plugins. They are blocking loading as well.

Comment: So they are all plugins files. Is there a way to have them all load in the footer?

Comment: Well, what about just cutting and pasting them back into desired position? I couldn't tell you without knowing how your project is setup.

Comment: How do you mean? Each plugin is loading its own files inside its own plugin folder. Is there anyway in my functions.php file to make them load in the footer?